# Graphic design outsourcing contracts?

Tags: contract, work

AIGA and others have a slew of contracts that can be used by graphic designers with their clients. But where can I find a contract that designers can use when they want to outsource projects to other designers?

Comment: It's pretty much the same. You're the client.

Comment: They have to send me the contract then. What if I want to make it myself, do I base it on a "work-for-hire" type of contract?

Comment: @Cyrus You create the contract, it's simpler. Base your contract on the same requirements as the ones that are required from you by your own clients, & should add even more since you're hiring someone doing similar services to yours. That can include payment schedule, cancellation, delivery, privacy, exclusivity, responsibility, editable files, etc. Important things: Stuff about no contact with your clients, final editable files delivered to you, revisions must be approved by you, to not use files for portfolio, use secure methods to transfer files, what you provide (eg. dropbox),  etc.

Comment: I wouldn't sign any contract that forbade usage in my portfolio.

Comment: @DA01 That's up to the OP to decide what goes in the contract, but it's good to be specific. At least now the OP knows you don't want to work for him/her if that's one of his/her requirement ;)

Comment: @go-meek agreed. But my point is that few designers would sign such a contract.